# How can I count records that are grouped?

Tags: sql

I want to count the number of rows that meet the criteria in this query:

```
Select DISTINCT(projects.project_id)
    , projects.project_name
    , CONVERT(char(11), projects.kickoff_date, 102) AS kickoff_date
    , status_phase.status_name
    , eal.eal_abbrv
    , tech_types.tech_name
from projects
INNER JOIN tech_assigned
    ON projects.project_id = tech_assigned.project_id
INNER JOIN tech_types
    ON tech_assigned.tech_id = tech_types.tech_id
inner join status_phase
    on projects.status_phase_id=status_phase.status_phase_id
inner join eal
    on projects.eal_id=eal.eal_id
where status_phase.status_id <= 2 
    order by eal.eal_abbrv
```

I want the count grouped by the eal.eal_name column but when I try to do this I get the dreaded "Column `'projects.project_id'` is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." error message. I can count the records by using the `Select COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(1)` functions but I need to count within the groups.

Comment: There is no `eal_name` mentioned in the query.  Second, why are you doing a `distinct` . . . are the joins producing too many rows?

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding in the eal.eal_name column since you didn't have it in your query.  So what you need to do is count() on the column you want get #s for, add in that column again, and then you'll need to add the GROUP BY clause and add every column you are selecting on.

```
Select DISTINCT(projects.project_id)
, projects.project_name
, count(eal.eal_name)
, eal.eal_name
, CONVERT(char(11), projects.kickoff_date, 102) AS kickoff_date
, status_phase.status_name
, eal.eal_abbrv
, tech_types.tech_name
from projects
INNER JOIN tech_assigned
ON projects.project_id = tech_assigned.project_id
INNER JOIN tech_types
ON tech_assigned.tech_id = tech_types.tech_id
inner join status_phase
on projects.status_phase_id=status_phase.status_phase_id
inner join eal
on projects.eal_id=eal.eal_id
where status_phase.status_id <= 2 
group by projects.project_id
, projects.project_name
, eal.eal_name
, CONVERT(char(11), projects.kickoff_date, 102)
, status_phase.status_name
, eal.eal_abbrv
, tech_types.tech_name
order by eal.eal_abbrv
```

Answer (score 0):

try using windowed functions...

like this...

```
    declare @table table (a int, b int)
    insert into @table
    values (0,0),(0,1),(0,1),(1,2)

    select *
    ,COUNT(*) over () as [count all]
    ,COUNT(*) over (partition by a) as [count as grouped by a]
    ,COUNT(*) over (partition by a,b) as [count as grouped by a and b]
    from @table T
```

my resultset is

```
    a   b   count all   count as grouped by a   count as grouped by a and b
    0   0   4           3                       1
    0   1   4           3                       2
    0   1   4           3                       2
    1   2   4           1                       1
```

in your query should be

```
    Select DISTINCT(projects.project_id)
                    , count(*) over (partition by eal.eal_name) as [count by eal_name]
        , projects.project_name
        , CONVERT(char(11), projects.kickoff_date, 102) AS kickoff_date
        , status_phase.status_name
        , eal.eal_abbrv
        , tech_types.tech_name
    from projects
    INNER JOIN tech_assigned
        ON projects.project_id = tech_assigned.project_id
    INNER JOIN tech_types
        ON tech_assigned.tech_id = tech_types.tech_id
    inner join status_phase
        on projects.status_phase_id=status_phase.status_phase_id
    inner join eal
        on projects.eal_id=eal.eal_id
    where status_phase.status_id <= 2 
        order by eal.eal_abbrv
```